# How to fix ImportError: No module named main

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to upgrade pip on kali linux using

`pip install --upgrade pip`

when I hit enter I get a message saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
       from pip._internal.cli.main import main
ImportError: No module named main
```

Comment: Cross-site dup: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025189/pip-is-not-working-importerror-no-module-named-pip-internal

Answer (score 4):

Try out:

```
python2 -m pip install --user --upgrade pip
```

or

```
python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade pip
```

Comment: it still shows up with the same error when I run `pip install pyinstaller`

Comment: Without being aware how sure it is, I would edit the import line in the pip file to "from pip._internal.cli import main" or wherever you track the main module is